# Generics. I have issues when cast an object

Tags: java, generics, rest-assured

When I use the `response.path()` method, it returns a list of objects (strings). I store this result in a list of integers, and surprisingly, it does not raise any exceptions. I'm even able to print the contents successfully.

[image]

I do not have the solution.

Comment: What you do want? you want an exception?

Comment: I do not understend how  List<Integer> hold strings?

Comment: Could you add the response to your question?

Comment: Images of text are [not well received](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) here. Please edit the question. Use copy-and-paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the use of raw type, the compiler skipped the generic check！！！

That is to say, if you use rawtype, you lose the compile-time checks when using generic types, which may extend errors to runtime.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List a = new ArrayList<String>(){{
        add("what");
        add("the");
        add("f**k");
    }};

    List<Integer> b = a;
    System.out.println(b); //[what, the, f**k]
     
    //It can be compiled successfully, but an error will be reported when running
    Integer aNumber = b.get(0); 

}
```

In your code, I think it may be that you did not specify the generic type of the `Response` object

Answer (score 0):

You can also use instanceOf operator and then cast for example like

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap();
map.put("A",11);
map.put("B",102);
map.put("C",new Dog());
map.put("D",new Exception("bla-bla"));
map.put("E","Hello");
```

so look at ur map type , it can take object as value so any object be it Integer , Float , Dog , Bussiness Object , new Thread , new Exception all are good to be inserted.

now the problem comes when u , iterating and access the values ...java dont know what comes out .. ***so it will give u classCastException ryt***.

**Intention : to extract value**

```
 int output = map.get("A");
```

/* so here you trying to access value based on key ryt
which is integer and u trying to save in integer ...but it is object for java as u declared map as Map<String,Object> ... correct not integer */

**Solution**

```
Object obj = map.get("A");
if(obj instanceOf Integer)
{
  Integer output = (Integer) map.get("A");
   // now u can use output
}
```